# Debugging Google Maps KML feed

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a Google Maps KML feed which stopped working a few days ago.  The URL is here: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=https://www.ikeyless.com/businesses.kml&ie=UTF8&ll=39.774769,-98.261719&spn=46.801033,78.222656&z=4&source=embed

I'm not able to determine the cause of what's preventing it from loading.  It passes validation... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file works.

I think you had an temporary problem with the file. Google Maps is caching your file after the first hit, unless you change the file name or add a parameter.

Go to your provided url and enter ?dummy=yyymmddhhii (Change into the current time ;)). After that, the file will show up correctly.

The best way is to add a dummy parameter with javascript with the actual date, so the file will parsed with the newest content.

Comment: You're saying the file works but when I test here with variables in the URL and on various computers I don't see the placemarks.

Comment: Probably you are to close within the map. The points are far away and you should change to satelite mode. Here is a screenshot: http://i52.tinypic.com/34sfhua.jpg